# Is there a way to force specific apps to run and remain in a specific order?

Tags: macbook-pro

I've been trying for days to figure out the correct way to phrase this question, so please do not hesitate to correct me.

I have four apps that I always run in full screen mode and I always have them in a specific order. It looks like this:

- Dashboard
- Spotify
- IRC App
- Desktop
- Browser
- Sublime Text

The problem I would like to solve is, even though I set them in this order, they don't always stay in that order. I can't figure out why. The browser, for example, will sometimes slide over to the left side of the desktop.

So two questions:

- Is there a way to have these specific apps open on start up?
- Is there a way to lock them into these positions, both on start up and during normal use?

I'm running a MacBook on OS X El Capitan v10.11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OS X 10.11 the default under **System Preferences** > **Mission Control** for the **Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use** is checked. So to not have your *Spaces* rearranged on you, uncheck the checkbox for that setting.

[image: Mission Control Preferences]

To have an App tied to a particular **Desktop**, open the target App on that **Desktop**, then control-click (right-click) the target App's **Dock Tile** and select: **Options** > Assign To > **This Desktop**

[image: Dock Tile > Options > This Desktop]

To have an App launch automatically upon Login, go to **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > *select the* **User** > *click* **Login Items** and add the App.

[image: Login Items]

Comment: I didn't see an option for "this desktop", only "keep in dock", "open at login" and "show in finder"

Comment: @Andrew Fox, I've updated my answer with some screenshots for each point. These are from an OS X 10.11.6 build.  If you do not see  **This Desktop** as shown in the second image then you'll need to provide more information then "_I didn't see an option for ..._"

Comment: I don't think that will work for full-screen applications, though.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/d9s6k4 Here is my screen shot

Comment: @Andrew Fox, The only time I've seen the Options context menu look like that is when the system defaults are in play. In other words when there is only one Desktop (Space) defined. I assumed from your question you already have multiple Desktops set up in Mission Control (the app not the preferences pane). If you do have multiple Desktops then this may be a case where you need to toggle the bit, so to speak, to fix it. Temporarily delete all but the first Desktop in Mission Control then logout/login and add back the Desktops. Does the context menu show correctly now?

Comment: I think I understand now. I have my apps in fullscreen mode, which I prefer, but what you're saying is to add a desktop and then assign it. I added a new desktop and then I do have the option to assign it to that desktop. I'll muck around with this for a bit and see how it works

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need a third-party tool to manage this, such as [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) ($10), [Startupizer](http://gentlebytes.com/startupizer/) ($10), or [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) ($36). With any of these applications (and probably others), you can set the order to launch applications in and optionally set delays in between them.